# docker-compose builds my container but does not run other containers within the file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am composing a solution with Prometheus, Grafana, cAdvisor and an "infinite-loop" container.

when I run "docker-compose up", it builds and run only my last container (which contains a ruby program to print out a string in an infinite-loop).

If I remove my container (infinite-loop), all other containers are created and run normally.

Why is it skipping the creation of the other containers when I specify my container?

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  prometheus_data: {}
  grafana_data: {}

networks:
  monitor-net:

services:

  prometheus:
    image: "prom/prometheus:latest"
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    #    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks: 
      - monitor-net

  grafana:
    image: "grafana/grafana:latest"
    container_name: grafana
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
#   restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks: 
      - monitor-net

  cadvisor:
    image: "google/cadvisor:latest"
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
    container_name: cadvisor
#    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks: 
      - monitor-net

  infinite-loop:
    image: "infinite-loop:latest"
    build:
      context: .
      #using custom Dockerfile as build argument
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-InfiniteLoop
    networks: 
      - monitor-net
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `Dockerfile-InfiniteLoop`? I suspect that the loop already starts infinitely during build, which is why the build might never stop.

Comment: May I also ask what the `infinite-loop` container is expected to do in the end?